# WebRTC with AngularJS: can't bind video stream to HTML video element

Tags: angularjs, webrtc

I am trying to make WebRTC enabled application. On client side, I am using AngularJS and on server side, I use NodeJS. I am having some trouble to bind video stream to video element ng-src.

Following is the Controller:

```
.controller('WebRTCController', function($scope){

      $scope.streams = [];

       getUserMedia({video : true , audio : true}, successCallback, errorCallback);

       function successCallback(newStream){


            $scope.streams.push(URL.createObjectURL(newStream));

            console.log('Angular: '+ $scope.streams)
       }

       function errorCallback(err){
        console.log('Some Error');
       }

    })
```

Here is the HTML page, (I use jade template)

```
div(ng-controller='WebRTCController')
       | Hello {{streams}}
       br
       video(ng-src='streams', autoplay='true')

       div(ng-repeat='stream in streams')
          video(ng-src='stream', autoplay)
```

Kindly, let me know if this is not the correct approach. I tried first in ng-repeat and then also gave streams to ng-src directly. Inside  the controller, when I print on console, I see the mediastream object (it is something like this : - "Angular: mediastream:4a15fb80-3aa7-4ddf-86b4-3b0cea498784") but I can't see any video on the view side.

Comment: This is a very obvious question, but mandatory: Do you click on "accept" to the browser question to use your webcam each time you call getUserMedia, right?

Comment: Of course, I do. I tried the similar example in pure HTML without AngularJs and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `$scope.$apply` in your callback to update the scope. Example:

```
function successCallback(newStream) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.streams.push(URL.createObjectURL(newStream));
    });
}
```

Comment: It gives the following error on browser console.

GET http://localhost:3000/stream [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 2ms]

HTTP load failed with status 404. Load of media resource http://localhost:3000/stream failed.

Comment: Try changing the last line in your Jade to `video(src='{{ stream }}', autoplay)`

Comment: I tried it but it did not work. Then I also tried 'video(src='{{ stream.blob }}', autoplay)' and it did nothing. Then I  tried 'video(src='stream.blob', autoplay)' and it showed the video element and it was like black triangle and showed nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an interpolation error, you might have to add the base url of the mediaStream to you whitelist config. For example:

```
streamApp.config(function ($sceDelegateProvider) {
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
    'self',                    // trust all resources from the same origin
    '*://www.youtube.com/**',  // trust all resources from `www.youtube.com`
    '*:blob:http://yourdomain.com/**'  // this might be how to test from mediaStream. 
  ]);
 })
```

You might have to mess around with it a little bit. Hope this helps